# Cannot run .net 3.5 web page on IIS Express thru VS2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have recently upgraded to VS2013.  I'm running on a Windows 8 Enterprise machine.  I am able to create a simple web site and compile it as .net 4.0 and it works fine with IIS Express.  However, immediately after testing the .net 4.0 web page, I create a new one as .net 3.5 and receive the following error when I try to compile the solution:

```
Error   1   An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
```

When I look in c:\users{userName}\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config it shows

```
    <site name="WebSite2" id="9">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\{userName}\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite2" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:63681:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main points to make:

1. Windows 8 does not come with the .NET Framework 3.5 installed by default. You need to add it under Control Panel > Programs and Features
2. IIS Worker Processes (Application Pools, `w3wp.exe`) can only use a single version of the CLR at a time (there are two choices: `2.0` and `4.0`, the `2.0` CLR includes version `3.5` of the .NET Framework)

I don't have experience with IIS Express, but presumably you can configure your application pool to use a specific version of the framework, look for the `<applicationPools>` element in your IIS configuration files.